# Warning from SAGA when doing Topographic Corrections?

Tags: dem, saga

I am trying to use SAGA for topographic corrections for the first time, however I am getting a warning that says:

> data not in the same grid

Can any one suggest ways of formatting the data (DEM and source images) so that it's properly handled?